# stay logged in in php application for +1 week

Tags: php, web-applications, authentication

We have a php application written in zend framework and are wondering what would be the best way if we wanted to keep our users logged in for more than a day, e.g. a week or even more.

Do we need sessions for that? (uses table space and memory?) or is it better to work with cookies? (security?)

Comment: What are you using at the moment?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is stateless, meaning the webserver will forget who you are after it served your request. Sessions are way around this. When using Sessions, browser and server will exchange an identifier on each request that lets the webserver connect previously stored  data to this particular requestor.

The ID is *usually* stored in Cookie. Set your Session Cookie to expire in one week and you are all set for keeping your users logged in for a week.

See

- [PHP Manual on Session Handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)
- [“Keep Me Logged In” - the best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354999/keep-me-logged-in-the-best-approach)
- [Keep Accounts Logged In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065436/keep-accounts-logged-in)

Comment: are you saying that we should keep sessions for one week? wouldn't that be using up session table data/memory? Or is that something that's not really a big problem, even with a lot of users?

Comment: @Jorre that depends on what you throw into the Session Storage and what *a lot* of users are and what hardware capacity the system has. Sooner or later any system will reach it's capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you do not need sessions. You are confusing two things:

- Sessions are used to store data server-side for a specific user. This will probably include the user name with which the user the logged in. Sessions are typically relatively short-lived (e.g. expire after a few minutes or hours of inactivity). Session cookies (i.e., cookies that expire after the user closes the browser) are typically used to associate a given user to a given session, though other other methods can be used, such as passing the session id in the URL (beware of session fixation in this case).
- For long lived logins, one typically stores the user credentials or some medium-term user credentials surrogate in a non-session cookie that's set to expire after a few weeks or months. Whenever the user does not have an active session associated with him, these credentials are used to initiate such session without user interaction.

So basically, cookies are used for two purposes – to store a short-lived (minites or hours) session id and to store user credentials for a few days/weeks/months.

Comment: I disagree to the second bullet point. Never use credentials in a Cookie. This is insecure. Also, there is no reason why the Session or it's cookie should be short lived. The Session Cookie being removed when the browser is closed is just the default setting. This can very much be changed to anything you want.

Comment: @Gordon It's only insecure if you make if it insecure. You can mark the cookie secure and then it'll only be sent via https.

Comment: That would only use HTTPS from the client to the server. Also, I dont see why I should use a second cookie when this can easily be handled with the Session Cookie alone. Just up the lifetime.

Comment: @Gordon What? In SSL/TLS it's not possible for a party to send unencrypted data while the other does -- what do you mean it "would only use HTTPS from the client to the server"?

Comment: I might be wrong, but see the description for [setcookie](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on the secure flag. But my main point is that you simply dont need a second cookie anyway.

Comment: @Gordon OK, I'll translate that description. Let's say the client has a cookie stored with the secure flag set. The client initiates an unencrypted connection to the relevant website – result: the cookie's not sent. Now, the client starts an encrypted with the same site – result: the cookie's sent. What the second part means is that the site may set the secure cookie both through an encrypted connection an through an unencrypted connection – though it would be stupid to do so through an unencrypted one.

Comment: @Gordon There are several reasons why may not want to use very long lived sessions – storage taken by the sessions, not wanting to mess with session garbage collection in PHP, because several things are cached in the session and deleting the session is the form of cache invalidation used, etc.

Comment: Yes. That's what I understood, hence only only from client to server. But still, what I really dont see is what the second cookie should be good for? If the session expired, then all the data associated with it is gone unless you persisted it somewhere. Why not just keep the session active through the session cookie then? Unless you throw megabyte after megabyte into it, space shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: @Gordon No, you don't need a session cookie if you change the expiration and the session save path (for file based sessions). However, using two cookies may be the easiest migration path for a system that currently relies on sessions being short (e.g. has stale cache a few times; for instance, the groups a user belongs to). It also allows using short-lived insecure session cookies that are transmitted via unencrypted connections for not-particularly-important stuff and a protected user/pass surrogate cookie for the important actions. So, what's more appropriate will depend.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Guess I just never ran into the need for this. I think I can agree to it then. Thanks for sharing :) - do you want me to clean up comments?

Comment: @Gordon I'd save the exchange for the posterity.

Comment: I agree with gordon. Never store credentials in a cookie. Store something so you can identify the user, but not his credentials. This could be a GUID or whatever. Also make sure that the user is unable to change his credentials without supplying them (Have him enter his password to change it etc.) On top of that be aware that his session can be hijacked by anyone who gets access to that persisted cookie. Keep this seperate from the actual session, so you can release the used space once the current browsing session expiers.

Answer (score 1):

"Remember me" is always a hole in a security, whatever you use - cookie or session - someone can (in theory) steal a cookie, and thus enter account without any password. There are ways to increase security, by allowing recalling only under same IP. Cookies are AFAIK less secure however that depends on way you implement auth. For instance, by keeping password hash in cookies you almost give intruder a real password (which is a no-no, it may be used on other webapps) as there are dictionaries to obtain simple passwords from hash. Salting hash helps not much.

All in all, session is the simplest and well enough way. Use tables if you use more than one webserver for an app, otherwise sessions on disk is ok.

Comment: You still use cookies to implement sessions, if someone intercepts the cookie he can hijack the session. So really, it doesn't make much sense to present a session vs cookies dichotomy. Session is a different, more abstract concept and cookies are a common piece in the implementation of such concept.

Comment: Session uses cookie, that's written in my 1st sentence. However, if cookie is stolen server still may compare user's IP and reject auto-entering. That's also mentioned ;)